# MariaDB query for max and min value in two fields

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

In this Database:

https://github.com/DiscoDurodeRoer/Database_pokemon/blob/master/1%C2%BA_generacion/scripts/mysql_pokemon.sql

I want to make a query to find the lowest pokemon with the most weight. How can I do that?

For example, I can make this query for the pokemon with max weight:

`SELECT nombre AS 'Nombre', peso AS 'Peso' FROM pokemon ORDER BY peso DESC LIMIT 1;`

The table is pokemon, weight is 'peso', height is 'altura'.

But I want to find the Pokemon with max weight and min height.

Thanks

Comment: we need more precision about how is your data base model etc, like update the scheme of your DB or something ? (so we can see what queries should be done)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the link to the DB. I have edited the post. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple clause in a ORDER BY condition so I think your answer is this :

```
SELECT nombre AS 'Nombre', peso AS 'Peso', altura AS 'altura' FROM pokemon ORDER BY peso DESC, altura ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think this is not correct, the result gives Snorlax with a weight of 460 and a height of 2.1. It gives the same result as if you only looked for the heaviest one.

Comment: the pokemon get ordered by peso desc, then for all the same result it order by altura. you just have one pokemon with peso at 460 so the result is correct, change some value in your table to 460 peso and you can see it's working